# Generate dynamically questions for QCM with Javascript -- Uncaught type error

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to dynamically create questions for a QCM in plain Javascript. The user press the button "generate" and the questions with its answer are supposed to appear.
I tried with a single question but I got this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node':
>   parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

I know this error is quite frequent but I did not find an answer to my question.

The Javascript code :

```
var question = ["What is your favorite color ?:","red","white","green"];

function createQuestion(q,tag){
var q = [];
var tag = document.createElement("div");
tag.innerHTML = q ;
}

function generate(){
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(createQuestion(question,"div"));
}
```

The HTML is just : 
`<button onclick = 'generate()'>generate</button>`

What is the mistake here ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is not returning the `tag` in your `createQuestion` function. Instead it returns `undefined` by default, which is obviously not a node.

```
function createQuestion(q,tag){
  var q = [];
  var tag = document.createElement("div");
  tag.innerHTML = q ;
  return tag;
}
```

This way your tag is returned.

EDIT:

Upon further inspection, I've found some other problems with the code. This should work for you.

The question is no longer a simple array, as it makes more sense to separate answers and question better.

```
var item = {
question: 'What is your favourite color?:',
answers: ['red', 'white', 'green']
}
```

Your current `createQuestion` function doesn't really make much sense. What this new one does is it creates an element, puts another element with the question in it, then creates a list and fills it with the answers.

```
function createQuestion(qItem) {
  var questionBox = document.createElement('div');
  question = document.createElement('div');
  question.innerHTML = qItem.question;
  questionBox.appendChild(question);

  var answers = document.createElement('ul');

  for (var i= 0; i < qItem.answers.length; i++){
    var answer = document.createElement('li');
    answer.innerText = qItem.answers[i];
    answers.appendChild(answer);
  }

  questionBox.appendChild(answers);
  return questionBox;
}

function generate(){
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(createQuestion(item));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't get the error anymore with the return statement. The question is still not appearing in the div though...

Comment: Reviewing the code better I've noticed some other problems with it. I'll try to write something in a bit.